# Can you be forgiven for a debt without paying?

Tags: money

Two part question here.

1. Curious if anyone knows of anything chazal says on the concept of owing people money and not paying back in a timely fashion, or not paying back at all, regarding the severity of it etc.
2. Can one be forgiven on a debt verbally? I.e., would it be a good practice to ask your friends to mochel you on any possible debts (like before Rosh Hashanah), even as small as pennies, and that would count as repaying anything that might be owed?

Comment: Do not forget that all debts are forgiven at Shemitta unless the term of the debt extends longer in which case it is forgiven at the next shemitta.

Comment: It says somewhere that one has to come back into this world to pay it back.